# Bootstrap 3 Media Query Breakpoints

Tags: css, media-queries

Is it okay/recommended to use Bootstrap 3 Media Query Breakpoints in my project even though I am not going to use bootstrap as framework? Because the client has a website that is not bootstrap made (not responsive) and my task is to make it responsive

Comment: It's just CSS, so of course it's OK. Whether it's recommended is relative. I think bootstrap's features are pretty well standardized at this point, so it's a good place to start or model to base your project off of especially if you aren't well versed in CSS and/or media queries.

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for your answer ! I just searching on the web for common break points and I find [this] (https://scotch.io/tutorials/default-sizes-for-twitter-bootstraps-media-queries#bootstrap-3-media-query-breakpoints)